# Fastest way to count number of occurrences in a Python list

Tags: python, list, repeat

I have a Python list and I want to know what's the quickest way to count the number of occurrences of the item, `'1'` in this list. In my actual case, the item can occur tens of thousands of times which is why I want a fast way.

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '7', '7', '10', '10']
```

Which approach: `.count` or `collections.Counter` is likely more optimized?

Comment: Is the list always sorted? Are you always counting the first item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the occurrences of a list item in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-calculate-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Comment: @JoshCaswell No the list is not sorted and I'd count any item. I wasn't sure which approach: `count` or `collections.Counter` was better optimized which is why I asked

Comment: @prrao Depends if you want to do this multiple times or not.

Comment: @jamylak Yes I want to do this multiple times, for multiple items.

Comment: @prrao It will still be better to use `.count`

Comment: @Jakob Thanks. `count` works fine for large lists

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
a = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '7', '7', '10', '10']
print a.count("1")
```

It's probably optimized heavily at the C level.

Edit: I randomly generated a large list.

```
In [8]: len(a)
Out[8]: 6339347

In [9]: %timeit a.count("1")
10 loops, best of 3: 86.4 ms per loop
```

Edit edit: This could be done with [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
a = Counter(your_list)
print a['1']
```

Using the same list in my last timing example

```
In [17]: %timeit Counter(a)['1']
1 loops, best of 3: 1.52 s per loop
```

My timing is simplistic and conditional on many different factors, but it gives you a good clue as to performance.

Here is some profiling

```
In [24]: profile.run("a.count('1')")
         3 function calls in 0.091 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.091    0.091 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.091    0.091    0.091    0.091 {method 'count' of 'list' objects}

        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Prof
iler' objects}



In [25]: profile.run("b = Counter(a); b['1']")
         6339356 function calls in 2.143 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.143    2.143 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:68(__contains__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:128(__instancecheck__)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.143    2.143 collections.py:407(__init__)
        1    1.788    1.788    2.143    2.143 collections.py:470(update)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Prof
iler' objects}
  6339347    0.356    0.000    0.356    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
```

Comment: Which approach do you think is better optimized? I guess the better option is case dependent?

Comment: @prrao. In this case `count` is ~20x faster than creating a `Counter`, but the same `Counter` can be used to retrieve counts of multiple different value at very low extra cost. If you need to count 20 or more values from the same list `Counter` will be more efficient than running `.count()` 20 times

Comment: I was working with data set of 1,000,000 integers  where the range of set was 100, i.e each element was repeated around 10,000 times. Using `Counter` instead of `.count` brought down my time by half. +1 for `Counter`.

Comment: And I was working with a list of 350,000 strings (urls): using Counter took less than a second while I had time to drink a smoothie waiting for .count() to be done, so +1 again for Counter :) (Indeed I was counting every distinct url so, as said before, it's better to use Counter in this case).

Comment: I must be missing something. Working with _list[long]_ datasets (containing `random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)` numbers, up to 50M of them)` , trying to count another `randint` with the same parameters, `.cont` is ~10 times faster than `Counter` (only try to count once). Also, I switched to _generators_ that `Counter` knows how to handle, but the combined times (generating the list/generator + counting) favors `list` and `.count`. The behavior is consistent across _Python3_ and _Python2_.

Answer (score 22):

By the use of **Counter** dictionary counting the occurrences of all element as well as most common element in python list with its occurrence value in most efficient way.

If our python list is:-

```
l=['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '7', '7', '10', '10']
```

**To find occurrence of every items in the python list use following:-**

```
\>>from collections import Counter

\>>c=Counter(l)

\>>print c

Counter({'1': 6, '2': 4, '7': 3, '10': 2})
```

**To find most/highest occurrence of items in the python list:-**

```
\>>k=c.most_common()

\>>k

[('1', 6), ('2', 4), ('7', 3), ('10', 2)]
```

**For Highest one**:-

```
\>>k[0][1]

6
```

For the item just use k[0][0]

```
\>>k[0][0]

'1'
```

**For nth highest item and its no of occurrence in the list use follow:-**

**for n=2 **

```
\>>print k[n-1][0] # For item

2

\>>print k[n-1][1] # For value

4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pandas`, by transforming the `list` to a `pd.Series` then simply use `.value_counts()`

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '7', '7', '10', '10']
a_cnts = pd.Series(a).value_counts().to_dict()

Input  >> a_cnts["1"], a_cnts["10"]
Output >> (6, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combination of lambda and map function can also do the job:

```
list_ = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
sum(map(lambda x: x=="b", list_))
:2
```

Answer (score -2):

You can convert list in string with elements seperated by space and split it based on number/char to be searched..

Will be clean and fast for large list..

```
>>>L = [2,1,1,2,1,3]
>>>strL = " ".join(str(x) for x in L)
>>>strL
2 1 1 2 1 3
>>>count=len(strL.split(" 1"))-1
>>>count
3
```