# strpbrk() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In some Python code I'm writing, I need to count the number of occurrences of any of a set of characters in a string. In other words, I need to count the total occurrences of characters [c1, c2, c3,...,cn] in a string.

In C, the function called `strpbrk()` that can be used to do this, often with special instructions on x86 processors to make it faster.

In Python, I have written the following code, but it is the slowest part of my application.

```
haystack = <query string>
gc_characters = 0
for c in ['c', 'C', 'g', 'G']:
    gc_characters += haystack.count(c)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I assume `haystack` is fairly large here?

Comment: You want number of occurences per character `c1,c2,c3...` etc?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh the total for all characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have gone a little overboard here, but the tl;dr is that is the original code is actually faster than (EDIT: macOS's) `strpbrk()`, but some `strpbrk()` implementations may be faster!

`str.count()` uses [this bundle of strange and beautiful magic](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) in its guts – no wonder it's fast.

The full code is available at https://github.com/akx/so55822235

## Python code

These approaches are in pure Python, including OP's original

```py
def gc_characters_original(haystack):
    gc_characters = 0
    for c in ("c", "C", "g", "G"):
        gc_characters += haystack.count(c)
    return gc_characters


def gc_characters_counter(haystack):
    counter = Counter(haystack)
    return sum(counter.get(c, 0) for c in ["c", "C", "g", "G"])


def gc_characters_manual(haystack):
    gc_characters = 0
    for x in haystack:
        if x in ("c", "C", "g", "G"):
            gc_characters += 1
    return gc_characters


def gc_characters_iters(haystack):
    gc_characters = haystack.count("c") + haystack.count("C") + haystack.count("g") + haystack.count("G")
    return gc_characters
```

## Cython extension wrapping `strpbrk()`

```
from libc.string cimport strpbrk

cdef int _count(char* s, char *key):
    assert s is not NULL, "byte string value is NULL"
    cdef int n = 0
    cdef char* pch = strpbrk (s, key)
    while pch is not NULL:
        n += 1
        pch = strpbrk (pch + 1, key)
    return n

def count(s, key):
    return _count(s, key)
```

...

```py
def gc_characters_cython(haystack_bytes):
    return charcount_cython.count(haystack_bytes, b"cCgG")
```

## Handmade C extension wrapping `strpbrk()`

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>

static unsigned int count(const char *str, const char *key) {
  unsigned int n = 0;
  char *pch = strpbrk(str, key);
  while (pch != NULL) {
    n++;
    pch = strpbrk(pch + 1, key);
  }
  return n;
}

static PyObject *charcount_count(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  const char *str, *key;
  Py_ssize_t strl, keyl;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#s#", &str, &strl, &key, &keyl)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "invalid arguments");
    return NULL;
  }
  int n = count(str, key);
  return PyLong_FromLong(n);
}

static PyMethodDef CharCountMethods[] = {
    {"count", charcount_count, METH_VARARGS,
     "Count the total occurrences of any s2 characters in s1"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL},
};

static struct PyModuleDef spammodule = {PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "charcount",
                                        NULL, -1, CharCountMethods};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_charcount(void) { return PyModule_Create(&spammodule); }
```

...

```py
def gc_characters_cext_b(haystack_bytes):
    return charcount.count(haystack_bytes, b"cCgG")


def gc_characters_cext_u(haystack):
    return charcount.count(haystack, "cCgG")
```

---

## Measurements

On my Mac, counting `cCgG` in an one-million-character string of random letters, i.e.

```py
haystack = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(1_000_000))
haystack_bytes = haystack.encode()
print("original", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_original(haystack), number=100))
print("unrolled", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_iters(haystack), number=100))
print("cython", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_cython(haystack_bytes), number=100))
print("c extension, bytes", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_cext_b(haystack_bytes), number=100))
print("c extension, unicode", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_cext_u(haystack), number=100))
print("manual loop", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_manual(haystack), number=100))
print("counter", timeit.timeit(lambda: gc_characters_counter(haystack), number=100))
```

yields these results:

```
original               0.34033612700000004
unrolled               0.33661798900000006
cython                 0.6542106270000001
c extension, bytes     0.46668797900000003
c extension, unicode   0.4761082090000004
manual loop           11.625232557
counter                7.0389275090000005
```

So, unless the `strpbrk()` implementation in my mac's `libc` is horribly underpowered (EDIT: which it is), it's just best to use `.count()`.

## EDIT

I added [glibc's `strcspn()`/`strpbrk()`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/fe92a91f1e713ba4951bc6e6162f8803dc76b816/string/strcspn.c) and it's startlingly faster than [the näive version of `strpbrk()` shipped with macOS](https://github.com/practicalswift/osx/blob/4c9b4581f398ec2d64f102508346cb9e8d764fbc/src/libc/string/FreeBSD/strpbrk.c):

```
original                       0.329256
unrolled                       0.333872
cython                         0.433299
c extension, bytes             0.432552
c extension, unicode           0.437332
c extension glibc, bytes       0.169704 <-- new
c extension glibc, unicode     0.158153 <-- new
```

`glibc` also has SSE2 and SSE4 versions of the functions, which would probably be even faster still.

## EDIT 2

I went back to this one more time since I had an epiphany about how glibc's `strcspn()`'s clever lookup table could be used for character counting:

```c
size_t fastcharcount(const char *str, const char *haystack) {
  size_t count = 0;

  // Prepare lookup table.
  // It will contain 1 for all characters in the haystack.
  unsigned char table[256] = {0};
  unsigned char *ts = (unsigned char *)haystack;
  while(*ts) table[*ts++] = 1;

  unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)str;
  #define CHECK_CHAR(i) { if(!s[i]) break; count += table[s[i]]; }
  for(;;) {
    CHECK_CHAR(0);
    CHECK_CHAR(1);
    CHECK_CHAR(2);
    CHECK_CHAR(3);
    s += 4;
  }
  #undef CHECK_CHAR
  return count;
}
```

The results are very impressive, outperforming the glibc implementation 4-fold and the original Python implementation 8.5-fold.

```
original                       | 6.463880 sec / 2000 iter | 309 iter/s
unrolled                       | 6.378582 sec / 2000 iter | 313 iter/s
cython libc                    | 8.443358 sec / 2000 iter | 236 iter/s
cython glibc                   | 2.936697 sec / 2000 iter | 681 iter/s
cython fast                    | 0.766082 sec / 2000 iter | 2610 iter/s
c extension, bytes             | 8.373438 sec / 2000 iter | 238 iter/s
c extension, unicode           | 8.394805 sec / 2000 iter | 238 iter/s
c extension glib, bytes        | 2.988184 sec / 2000 iter | 669 iter/s
c extension glib, unicode      | 2.992429 sec / 2000 iter | 668 iter/s
c extension fast, bytes        | 0.754072 sec / 2000 iter | 2652 iter/s
c extension fast, unicode      | 0.762074 sec / 2000 iter | 2624 iter/s
```

Comment: This frankly just makes me very impressed by `.count()`

Comment: @modesitt Ayep. Looks like there's been quite some optimization gone into it... https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h

Comment: Very cool collection of comparisons here. I figured that the maximum possible speed would be from some implementation using _mm_cmpistrX(), but that may not be true depending on what string implementation Python uses internally....

Comment: @leecbaker @modesitt Turns out macOS's `strpbrk()` is dog slow compared to `glibc`'s!

Comment: I added one more implementation that's a lot faster still.

Answer (score 1):

`.count` will iterate over `haystack` every time you call it - but is [heavily optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452678/fastest-way-to-count-number-of-occurrences-in-a-python-list) over the alternatives I suggest here. It depends on how many characters are in your real case. You can try

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter(haystack)
gc_characters = sum(cnt.get(e, 0) for e in ['c', 'C', 'g', 'G']])
```

as this will iterate over the string once and store the counts of every occurring character. It may be marginally faster to only look for the characters you care about and using a set for those such characters for faster `__contains__`.

```
gc_chars = {'c', 'C', 'g', 'G'}
counts = {e: 0 for e in gc_chars}

for c in gc_chars:
    if c in gc_chars:
        counts[c] += 1

gc_characters = sum(counts.values())
```

If you provide more details of the composition of `hastack` and how often this is called, we could try to help you more.

### Caching

Another idea is that if `hastack` is frequently the same, you could perhaps keep an in-memory cache of the answer

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def haystack_metric(hastack):
     return sum(haystack.count(c) for c in ['c', 'C', 'g', 'G']))
```

(with whatever implementation you settle on). You could also explore [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) - but I have little experience with it.

Comment: I tried this too – using `Counter` is much slower than the OP's original idea.

Comment: Yeah unless he is looking at many more characters than the 4 provided, I think `Counter` will remain way slower for quite some time.

Comment: Why implement a custom cache decorator, when functools provides `lru_cache` already?

Comment: That `cache` decorator is probably better replaced with `functools.lru_cache` (especially since it dangerously ignores `**kwargs`!).