# Division between dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, division

I have two dicts:

```
dict_1 = {'A': ['red', 'red', 'blue'],
          'B': ['red', 'green'],
          'C': ['blue', 'green'], ....}

dict_2 = {'A': Counter({'red': 2, 'blue': 1}),
          'B': Counter({'red': 1, 'green': 1}),
          'C': Counter({'blue': 1, 'green': 1}), ....}
```

I need to do some simple division between them and later plot them pairwise. The desired outcome is like this or anything that can do the division:

```
fraction = {'A': [2/3, 1/3],
            'B': [1/2, 1/2],
            'C': [1/2, 1/2], ....}
```

Right now, I can only get the first digit divided, any advice will be appreciated!
Here's my code:

```
fraction = { key: [v/len(colorz)] for namez, colorz in dict_1.items() 
                          for name, color in dict_2.items() 
                          for k, v in color.items() }
```

Comment: Do you want those fractions as strings? Also, `dict_1` and `dict_2` are just different expressions of the same data, right?

Comment: No, I don't want those fractions as strings. Yes, dict_1 and dict_2 have the same key but dict_2 counted the frequencies of dict_1 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version using Fractions.

```
from fractions import Fraction
{k: [Fraction(v[i], sum(v.values())) for i in v] for k, v in dict_2.items()}
```

Answer (score 4):

`.count` is [pretty fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822235/strpbrk-in-python/55822499#55822499), so I am not using `dict_2` with the `Counter`, but it is fine to use it.

```
fraction = {k: [l.count(e)/len(l) for e in set(l)] for k, l in dict_1.items()}
```

but this is meant to be short not necessarily efficient. If it needs to be faster, you can do something else. if you want them as strings then

```
fraction = {k: [f'{e.count(l)}/{len(l)}' for e in set(l)] for k, l in dict_1.items()}
```

and if you want them as strings of reduced fractions use the [`fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) module

Comment: It's great, but  there must be l.count(e). And if the key is 'B' the result is [1/2] and not [1/2,1/2].