# Count the identical pairs in two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My list has

```
a = [1,2,3,4,2,7,3,5,6,7]
b = [1,2,3,1,2,5,6,2,6,7]
```

I need to count if `a[i]==b[i]`.

For the above example, the answer should be

```
6
```

Detail description of answer is

```
a[0]==b[0] (1==1)
a[1]==b[1] (2==2)
a[2]==b[0] (3==3)
a[4]==b[4] (2==2)
a[8]==b[8] (6==6)
a[9]==b[9] (7==7)
```

Comment: I need to count how many identical values(a[i]==b[i]) are in the lists. I got the answer from below. thanks for asking.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In a one-liner:

```
sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

Comment: `sum(1 for x, y in zip(a, b) if x == y)` can be quite a lot faster, depending on how often the comparison is False, [as I also recently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56288015/4042267).

Answer (score 15):

One way would be to `map` both lists with [`operator.eq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) and take the `sum` of the result:

```
from operator import eq

a = [1,2,3,4,2,7,3,5,6,7]
b = [1,2,3,1,2,5,6,2,6,7]

sum(map(eq, a, b))
# 6
```

---

Where by mapping the `eq` operator we get either `True` or `False` depending on whether items with the same index are the same:

```
list(map(eq, a, b))
# [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use some of Python's special features:

```
sum(i1 == i2 for i1, i2 in zip(a, b))
```

This will

- pair the list items with `zip()`
- use a generator expression to iterate over the paired items
- expand the item pairs into two variables
- compare the variables, which results in a boolean that is also usable as `0` and `1`
- add up the `1`s with `sum()`

Comment: I prefer your method to mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator expression, take advantage of `A == A` is equal to 1 and `A != A` is equal to zero.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,2,7,3,5,6,7]
b = [1,2,3,1,2,5,6,2,6,7]
count = sum(a[i] == b[i] for i in range(len(a)))
print(count)

6
```

Comment: @Carsten It is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(np.array(a) == np.array(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

A little similar to @yatu's solution, but I save an import, I use `int.__eq__`:

```
print(sum(map(int.__eq__, a, b)))
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: or just with some lovely lambda  `sum(map(lambda x,y : x==y, a, b))`

Comment: @Daria `lambda` isn't lovely nor efficient here