# Why is the 'all' implementation slower than writing a for loop

Tags: python

I get a list and want to know if all elements are identical.
For lists with a high number of elements, that are indeed all identical, the conversion into a `set` is fast, but otherwise going over the list with early exit is performing better:

```
def are_all_identical_iterate(dataset):
    first = dataset[0]
    for data in dataset:
        if data != first:
            return False
    return True

# versus

def are_all_identical_all(dataset):
    return all(data == dataset[0] for data in dataset)
# or
def are_all_identical_all2(dataset):
    return all(data == dataset[0] for data in iter(dataset))
# or
def are_all_identical_all3(dataset):
    iterator = iter(dataset)
    first = next(iterator)
    return all(first == rest for rest in iterator)

NUM_ELEMENTS = 50000
testDataset = [1337] * NUM_ELEMENTS # all identical

from timeit import timeit
print(timeit("are_all_identical_iterate(testDataset)", setup="from __main__ import are_all_identical_iterate, testDataset", number=1000))
print(timeit("are_all_identical_all(testDataset)", setup="from __main__ import are_all_identical_all, testDataset", number=1000))
```

My results:
0.94 seconds,
3.09 seconds,
3.27 seconds,
2.61 seconds

The for loop takes less than have the time (3x) of the `all` function. The `all` function is supposed to be the [same implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

What is going on?
I want to know why the loop is so much faster and why there is a difference between the last 3 implementations. The last implementation should have one compare less, because the iterator removes the first element, but that shouldn't have this kind of impact.

Comment: You are doing the index lookup `dataset[0]` repeatedly in the `all` call, while you store the result in a local variable in the iteration.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I tried changing that, it doesn't make much difference. And `are_all_identical_all3` already  does not do that.

Comment: Answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288015/why-is-a-for-loop-so-much-faster-to-count-true-values/56291247#56291247 can answer yours. TLDR: usage of generators inside `all` function is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56299302/4401979) other SO post one cause could be that:

> The use of a generator expression causes overhead for constantly
>   pausing and resuming the generator.

Anyway I suggest two another approaches that looks faster using `map`:

```
def are_all_identical_map(dataset):
    for x in map(lambda x: x == dataset[0], dataset):
        if not x:
            return False
    return True

%%timeit
are_all_identical_map(testDataset)
#7.5 ms ± 64.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

and

```
%%timeit
(map(lambda x: x == dataset[0], dataset)) and True
#303 ns ± 13.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Your map implementation is fast, because your indentation is wrong. You always return True or False in the first loop cycle, so you're not really looking at all items. After fixing it, it is slow.

Comment: Now it's fixed. But the times need to be compared to the other implementation, because I don't know on what kind of machine it runs. And I don't know what your second implementation is supposed to be...

Comment: Yes, you were right, thank you! I made a quick fix for now. Later I will make a comparison with other solutions.