# What are the true time complexities of working with sets/dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, python-3.7

#### **Background**

I've been looking into a few ways to do essentially the same thing and would like some input on time complexity and whether it is true to the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) or not -- and why the general differences in speed exist. I'm using Python 3.7 for my tests (cpython).

More information on time complexity [here](https://stackabuse.com/big-o-notation-and-algorithm-analysis-with-python-examples/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642155/what-is-time-complexity-of-a-list-to-set-conversion).

---

#### **Testable Code**

```py
import timeit

def test1():
    new_d = {}
    for i in range(0, 50000):
        new_d[i] = None
        
def test2():
    new_s = set()
    for i in range(0, 50000):
        new_s.add(i)

def test3():
    new_l = list(range(0, 50000))
    new_s = set(new_l)

def test3b():
    new_s = set(range(0, 50000))

def test4():
    new_l = list(range(0, 50000))
    new_d = dict.fromkeys(new_l)

def test4b():
    new_d = dict.fromkeys(range(0, 50000))

def test5():
    new_l = list(range(0, 50000))
    new_d = {key: None for key in new_l}

def test5b():
    new_d = {key: None for key in range(0, 50000)}

tests = [test1, test2, test3, test3b, test4, test4b, test5, test5b]
for test in tests:
    print(timeit.timeit(test, number=10000))
```

---

#### **Reasoning**

So above are 5 methods to do ***what seem to be*** very similar operations. The idea behind all of them is to take a range and add it to a hashed type object (set or dict) in order to do O(1) lookups.

> **test1**: `Create a dict          -> iterate range -> add to dict`
> **test2**: `Create a set           -> iterate range -> add to set`
> **test3**: `List function on range ->  [automatic]  -> set function on list`
> **test3b**: `.    [automatic]      ->  [automatic]  -> set function on range`
> **test4**: `List function on range ->  [automatic]  -> dict from keys on list`
> **test4b**: `.    [automatic]      ->  [automatic]  -> dict from keys on range`
> **test5**: `List function on range ->  [automatic]  -> dict comprehension on list`
> **test5b**: `.    [automatic]      ->  [automatic]  -> dict comprehension on range`

Now to me (not an expert), the general logic behind all 5 of these is very similar, which is iterate the range and add to a hash table. If anything, I would guess that `test1` and `test2` would complete before others because they don't create a list and then iterate that list (On*2) and should complete in a single iteration.

I would also guess that each **b** function would be faster than its counterpart by an O(n) amount.

And then last I would guess that `test1` would be nearly the same as `test4b` (and `test4`, `test5`, and `test5b`), `test2` would be nearly the same as `test3b` (and `test3`)

---

#### **Results**

But alas, I'm here, so my assumptions are incorrect.

Methods: I tested on ranges `1000` (average of 3), `2000` (average of 3), `3000` (average of 3), `50000` (average of 2), `100000` (single run) and all with `timeit.timeit(number=10000)`.

```
TOTAL TIME (truncated)
         test1      test2      test3      test3b     test4      test4b     test5      test5b
1000     0.5094     0.7135     0.2758     0.2377     0.3735     0.3424     0.5173     0.4591
2000     1.0769     1.4383     0.6109     0.5161     0.7880     0.7226     1.0211     0.9565
3000     1.7337     2.1061     0.8848     0.7470     1.3066     1.1763     1.6431     1.6390
50000   34.6455    37.0113    16.0184    19.6853    35.4731    32.4986    40.2696    41.2130
100000  84.9230    89.7245    55.3949    47.8195    82.1506    75.7063    94.4856    84.2978

ADJUSTED TIME PER 1000 (rounded)
         test1      test2      test3      test3b     test4      test4b     test5      test5b
1000     0.5094     0.7135     0.2758     0.2378    0.3736      0.3430     0.5174     0.4591
2000     0.5385     0.7192     0.3055     0.2581    0.3940      0.3613     0.5106     0.4783
3000     0.5779     0.7021     0.2950     0.249     0.4355      0.3921     0.5477     0.5464
50000    0.6929     0.7402     0.3204     0.3937    0.7095      0.6500     0.8054     0.8243
100000   0.8492     0.8972     0.5539     0.4782    0.8215      0.7571     0.9449     0.8430
```

---

#### **Observations and Questions**

**Fastest**: `test3b` is nearly always fastest followed shortly by `test3` (except at 50,000)
**Slowest**: `test2` is slowest at small amounts, then `test5b` at 50,000, and finally `test5` at 100,000

The speed of the test does not linearly grow with change in `n`, it is growing higher than the difference in `n`. Normalized to `per 1000` I expected to see much closer numbers. I also expect it, if anything, to reach a maximum per 1000 and then level off. So, as I have already admitted, my assumptions and expectations are wrong.

Can you help me out with understanding this performance? It's clear that `test3b` is the fastest method by far, and that `test2` performs poorly in comparison, even though they do similar things. I imagine it has to do with memory management and allocation of space for the hash table? My main question is... what's happening here and why?

Comment: Not an explanation at all, but for loops in Python are slow, so it makes sense that test1 and test2 are slow in comparison with test3b (test3). Also it makes sense that test3 is slower than test3b because you are creating a list first.

Comment: Agreed @DanielMesejo that all `b` should be faster than counterpart and it seems to follow that way, though I probably expected a larger difference -- maybe not testing enough values.

Comment: Iterating with `for` loop is slow because of generators, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288015/why-is-a-for-loop-so-much-faster-to-count-true-values

Comment: I guess, but you should not expect to get a larger difference because the overall time is dominated by the creation of the set/dictionary

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to simply test membership in a contiguous range, you don't want any of these - just directly test `N in range(0, 50000)`.  A `range` object is tiny (basically three ints), and membership is directly computed rather than involving any sort of lookup.

Comment: The `range` is just a constant to generate data. The idea wouldn't be to test within a range since that is math based and could be done near instantly. It's just representing a data set. The question is in creating your hash table (Set or Dict), how can it be done the fastest and why are some methods faster than others when they appear to function the same?