# table() equivalent function(from R) in Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I am trying to get the table() equivalent function(from R) in Python.

I have a table :

```
+-----+--------+
|  Sr | Gender |
+-----+--------+
| 123 |    M   |
+-----+--------+
| 124 |    M   |
+-----+--------+
| 126 |    M   |
+-----+--------+
| 127 |    F   |
+-----+--------+
| 128 |    F   |
+-----+--------+
```

Expected output :

```
+---+---+
| M | F |
+---+---+
| 3 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

in R it could be easily achieved by `table(df$Gender)`

But not sure how to achieve this in Python. I have tried crosstab() and pivot_table() but not able to get the exact syntax.

Comment: `Counter` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452678/fastest-way-to-count-number-of-occurrences-in-a-python-list

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Hi Sayandip, i can use pandas but not sure how to achieve above output by using available Python functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it a few ways, depending on what you want to get:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [629]: df.Gender.value_counts()                                                                                                                                                             
Out[629]: 
M    3
F    2

or

print(pd.value_counts(df['Gender']).to_frame().T.to_string(index=False))                                                                                                             
 M  F
 3  2

In [630]: pd.DataFrame(df.Gender.value_counts())                                                                                                                                               
Out[630]: 
   Gender
M       3
F       2

In [632]: pd.DataFrame(df.Gender.value_counts()).T                                                                                                                                             
Out[632]: 
        M  F
Gender  3  2
```

or for your exact:

```
In [643]: pd.DataFrame(df.Gender.value_counts()).rename(columns={'Gender': ''}).T                                                                                                              

  M  F
  3  2
```

Comment: I don't know how can I thank you enough for teaching me `pd.read_clipboard()`!! This is huge!

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yeah, it's cool, i've been using it a lot since i found out about it

Comment: I intend to do the same :D